# Omitting "da" in casual speech

Tags: particles, feminine-speech, casual

How acceptable is it to omit "da" in casual speech in phrases such as

-- chokoreto ga suki (da) yo

-- boku wa daigakusei (da)

And so on..... Do it also depend if it's a male or female talking?

Answer (score 2):

I think omitting "da" in casual speech is common.

I feel chokoreto ga suki yo is mainly used by female. If you omit だ in だよ like that, it becomes ladylike manner of speaking.

boku wa daigakusei is no problem. Or rather, that kind of だ is commonly omitted in casual speech.